# Why do I get 3221226356 error when calling free in C?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, free

I'm learning C and doing some coding challenges to learn.
While doing 1 challenge I need to create a dynamic 2D char array.

I am trying to follow some other StackOverflow answers to create the 2D array dynamically.

I'm able to create it, but while trying to free the memory, I get the error 3221226356.
Below is my code:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);

        char **s = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            s[i] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
            //memset(s[i], '\0', 1000);
            scanf("%s", &s[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("%s - %d\n", &s[i], strlen(&s[i]));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            printf("Freeing %d\n", i);
            //char *tmp = &s[i];
            free(s[i]);
        }

        printf("Freeing s\n");

        free(s);

        if (argc > 1)
        {
            char xx[100];
            scanf("%s", xx);
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

And an example run of the code with output:

```
2
xx
sss
xx - 2
sss - 3
Freeing 0

[process exited with code 3221226356]
```

I've tried calling free on &s[i] as well as *s[i] but both result in an error.
My compiler is GCC.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `malloc` and `free` calls look okay, but you corrupt the pointers to the strings by `scanf`'ing into `&s[i]` instead of `s[i]`. (The `%s` format and its cousin `%[` take strings to fill, which are already passed as pointers. Also: Please activate warnings with `-Wall`. They will show you format mismatches.)

Comment: All of your `&s[i]` should just be `s[i]`.  `&s[i]` has type `char **`, so cannot be used with `scanf`, `printf`, etc.  `s[i]` has type `char *` which is what you want.  Your compiler should have warned about those mistakes.  In practice, the pointers will have the same value, so it will "work", but it's not right.

Comment: M. Oehm is right, although if you wish to save your string at a specific index , you could use `scanf('%s",&s[i][index]` , `scanf("%s",s[i])` is equivelant to `scanf("%s",&s[i][0]` .

Comment: Note: 3221226356 is 0xC000 0374.

Comment: The best first step is to enable; all compiler warnings.  A good compiler will warn about `scanf("%s", &s[i]); ... printf("%s - %d\n", &s[i], strlen(&s[i]));` and speed along your programming.

Comment: Everyone saying my scanf is wrong. How should I get user input then? Should I create a temp variable and strcpy it?

But is that the reason the calls to free are breaking?

Comment: And that seems to have worked.  
But now I have another question, will I not have unfreed memory at the end? The malloc I am calling on tmp? Or is that freed when I call free(s[i]) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the commends about &s[i] led me to a sort of obvious solution.
To create a temp variable for scanf.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    char **s = malloc(n * sizeof(char *));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        //s[i] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(char));
        char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char));
        //memset(s[i], '\0', 1000);
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        s[i] = tmp;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s - %d\n", s[i], strlen(s[i]));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Freeing %d\n", i);
        //char *tmp = &s[i];
        free(s[i]);
    }

    printf("Freeing s\n");

    free(s);

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        char xx[100];
        scanf("%s", xx);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```